# How to add comma/and between string array in java

Tags: java, arrays, string

i get an array of authors from json response and i have to display authors name in TextView(android) in proper format like =>Viraj, Chetan and George R. R. Martin
my code work fine, but it's a mess....

```
public class SeprateAuthors {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String[] authors0 = {"a", "b"};
    String[] authors1 = {"a", "b", "c"};
    String[] authors2 = {"a", "b", "c","d"};
    String[] authors3 = {"a", "b", "c","d","e","f"};
    
    System.out.println(displayAuthors(authors0));
    System.out.println(displayAuthors(authors1));
    System.out.println(displayAuthors(authors2));
    System.out.println(displayAuthors(authors3));        
}
public static String displayAuthors(String[] authors) {
    StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
    String stringAuthors="";
    String prefixComma = ", ";
    String prefixAnd = " and ";
    if ((authors != null) && (authors.length > 0)) {
        
        for (int i = 0; i < authors.length; i++) {
            if (i < authors.length - 2) {
                stringBuilder.append(authors[i]).append(prefixComma);
            } else {
                stringBuilder.append(authors[i]).append(prefixAnd);
            }
        }
        //  Java Remove extra Characters("and ") from String
        stringAuthors = stringBuilder.substring(0, stringBuilder.length() - 4);
    }
    return stringAuthors;
}
```

}

Comment: Normally if your code works and you want comments, you put your code on the code review site: [codereview.se]

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because should be moved to Code Review.

Comment: @markspace I've flagged for migration to CR per [_this meta post_](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/266749/1575353). In the future please do this instead of voting to close for that reason. See [_Does being on-topic at another Stack Exchange site automatically make a question off-topic for Stack Overflow?_](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/287400/1575353), [_Migration of code questions from Stack Overflow to Code Review_](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/266749/1575353) & [this answer to _A guide to Code Review for Stack Overflow users_](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5778/120114)

Comment: I didn't know that was an option under flagging, thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 2):

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

class SeprateAuthors {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String[] authors0 = {"a", "b"};
        String[] authors1 = {"a", "b", "c"};
        String[] authors2 = {"a", "b", "c", "d"};
        String[] authors3 = {"a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f"};

        System.out.println(displayAuthors(authors0));
        System.out.println(displayAuthors(authors1));
        System.out.println(displayAuthors(authors2));
        System.out.println(displayAuthors(authors3));
    }

    public static String displayAuthors(String[] authorsArray) {

        List<String> authors = Arrays.asList(authorsArray);

        if (authors.size() == 1) {
            return authors.get(0);
        } else {
            String lastAuthor = authors.get(authors.size() - 1);
            List<String> firstAuthors = authors.subList(0, authors.size() - 1);

            String firstAuthorsString = String.join(", ", firstAuthors);

            return  firstAuthorsString + " and " + lastAuthor;
        }
    }
}
```

This should work for you.

Output:

```
a and b
a, b and c
a, b, c and d
a, b, c, d, e and f
```